# SSD or CPU? iMac Late 2012

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I just installed 32 GB of ram on an old iMac late 2012 with a standard HD, 2.9 GHz i5 processor and a GeForce GTX 660M video cards.

I was hoping it would be a lot quicker but only saw a small improvement.

Just wondering if the CPU or HD is holding me back. I'm doing a lot of print and web stuff with illustrator if that helps.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because harware issues are outside the scope of this network

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's the HDD. Get the fastest SSD you can reasonably afford. Just starting your computer will be 3x faster, at least, if you jump to a good SSD.

One other thing, Illustrator runs like a dehydrated donkey. It's so poorly coded as to be a joke. Single threaded, mostly, too. Doesn't matter how powerful your GPU/CPU combo, it dawdles. Never above about 15fps, often much lower.

Try Affinity Designer to see how fast scrolling, panning and zooming can operate on your Mac.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46187/discussion-between-dv-and-confused).